# metro app without the UI?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am working on a porting a windows desktop app to metro. In its current form it is a command line tool with no UI support. I want the app to run on top of winRT also as a command line tool.Is that possible? If yes, how should i proceed? I am developing in VS 2102 on windows 8.

PS: i am still researching on how to do the porting. Although there are plenty of resources for how to make a metro app with UI , there is none for my requirement. So am not sure if that is even possible. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand, what is your requirement? It's just a command-line tool?

Comment: to make a command line tool that uses only the winRT api . Basically so that it can also run on windows tablets. Is that possible?

Comment: It is to create a command line tool that can run on WinRT API's . Basically so that it can also run on Windows RT tablets. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated template on Visual Studio Gallery:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3c68246b-8103-467c-9557-894b1f837591